# error in python code while creating an object

Tags: python-3.x, oop

An error is coming while declaring an object . Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import*

class Bill_App:

     def _init_(self,root):

      pass



root=Tk()

obj = Bill_App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

error:-

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\rish6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Bill_App\Bill.py", line 9, in <module>
    obj = Bill_App(root)

TypeError: Bill_App() takes no arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is coming due to wrong syntax of init method.

```
def _init_(self,root):
```

it should be **[__init__](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53318475/12210002)** -> `def __init__(self,root):`

**Changed code**

```
from tkinter import*

class Bill_App:

     def __init__(self,root):

      print('object is created'+str(root))



root=Tk()

obj = Bill_App(root)

root.mainloop()
```